# FFmpeg - Handling changing input audio codecs

Tags: ffmpeg

The current input stream is hls and output is lowered multi-bitrate hls streams. The incoming hls stream has a secondary stream which is switched when the primary stream is unavailable. Currently, the secondary stream's audio codec is mp2a whilst the primary is aac. When this switch occurs, I'm losing the audio on the output streams. Is there a way to compensate for this switch?

Comment: No. Stream decoder change in the middle of transcoding is not supported.

Comment: Have you ever seen a successful way to monitor the incoming stream, and restart the process if the codec is changed?

Comment: All good; I resolved this issue by monitoring ffprobe with a bash script and restarting if the audio codec has been changed.